# WordPress with .tel domains, is it possible?

Tags: domains, wordpress, top-level-domains, domain-extension

Is it possible to host a WordPress site with `.tel` domain. When I checked for `.tel` extension website, all the site's are similar in design.

Answer (score 2):

Domains and hosting are separate things.

You buy a domain (`.tel` for example). You point it to hosting.

What you put on your hosting is entirely up to you - so long as your hosting allows you to install WordPress (99% of them will) you are fine.

You could even point your domain to a `wordpress.com` site if you already have it hosted on a free service.

Comment: I undeleted my answer because I looked into it further. Apparently you're not actually able to do this. The `TELNIC` has an editor that you use with your domain, it's not so much that you can use normal DNS and hosting with it from what I can tell. But I'm not going to buy a `.tel` just to try it.

Answer (score 2):

I contacted 101domain.com, where there is an ".tel Web Hosting Service". In the support email, they say, "The .TEL registry requires all domains to use their specific DNS servers, which means that you cannot modify DNS records."

So, if you cannot modify the DNS records, you cannot use your own hosting service or use WordPress.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible since 2017. See [here](https://wiki.hexonet.net/wiki/TEL#.TEL_Updates_on_March_13th.2C_2017):

> As of March 13, 2017, previous DNS restrictions have been lifted by the registry, allowing .TEL registrants the freedom to choose how to use and host their .TEL domain names.

Standard websites are configured with [Telhosting](https://www.do.tel/manage-your-tel/) now. They are still available, but optional.

Answer (score 1):

You can host any type site with `.tel` TLD, assuming you have the domain and an hosting space.

Comment: This is incorrect. You cannot host a domain on a `.tel` domain; all domains under that TLD are forced to point to a server operated by the registry. It's pretty useless.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:**
While my original answer keeps being the official explanation, I just got my hosting to add my .tel domain as a regular one. I tested everything and works as any other domain; created subdomains and all. My take is that, either over time hosting companys gave up on inforcing the original behaviour of .tel domains, or that some companys don't really care that much about the planned restriction on .tel domains.

*In case anyone is interested my .tel hosting is in DreamHost and, though their control panel prevents you from adding a .tel domain, it doesn't say it can't be done, only that you can't add it through their panel because it is a "protected domain name"; but support added the domain name through their backoffice  to the panel, no questions asked, and it justs behaves like a normal hosting.*

So: *Is it possible to host a WordPress site with .tel domain?* **Yes**, I'm doing it.

**MY ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

---

.tel domains are an exception to the rule. They are special TLDs. You can not point them to any server, create subdomains, etc. The "website" will be stored as data in a dns record. It seemed an interesting idea when it was created, but it has ended up being useless. As of today (they keep disappearing) this an example of what one looks like http://midmichigan.tel/.

[From Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.tel):

> In contrast to other top-level domains, tel information is stored
>   directly within the Domain Name System (DNS), within the actual domain
>   name record, as opposed to the DNS simply returning details (such as
>   IP addresses) of the machines on which information can be found. For
>   example, users who register a .tel domain using Telnic name servers
>   cannot create a type A Resource Record with the IP address of their
>   own host. A user who wants to host a web site or run an own web server
>   has to set own or providers' name servers [sic].

---

Answer (score 0):

To directly answer your question, YES. a `.tel` domain is just like a `.com` or `.org` like anyone else uses. The extension/suffix does not affect what you can host on the site (Unless you use a `.edu` you have to be a registered educational institute, or a `.xxx` domain which is targeted towards adult websites. There are some similar cases. Please read the first few paragraphs here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.tel and you will see that while you may technically host anything you want (generally available) it's targeted toward communications and directory websites.

A domain name, hosting, and a website are three separate entities. If a domain NAME is available and you choose to purchase it (lease) then you will point it to the servers that HOST your WEBSITE. A web HOST just serves the pages (WordPress?) and your WEBSITE is the files being served.

What "sites" are similar in design? The `.tel` registrars? That's alright, you only use their sites to rent the DOMAIN. Please clarify your question.

Comment: When i Google for .TEl domains i can't even see a single domain in search list. And all the domain name's have similar template and hosted in Telnic Registry itself. http://www.telnic.org/telforyou-landing.html

Comment: @DOCTYPE - I can register one from a registrar just like any other domain, you're looking in the wrong place. The TELNIC does not actually sell the domains, they authorize the resellers to do so. https://www.webnames.ca/3step/buy/TelDomainSearch.aspx?domain=doctype.tel Also see the terms: https://www.webnames.ca/content/webnames/webnames_AcceptableUsePolicy_terms.asp

Comment: @DOCTYPE - And a quote from the TEL FAQ site: `"Those who already have a website can use .TEL to point to their current site. This method usually gives a search engine ranking boost to the website being linked to from their .TEL."`